# findOneAndUpdate in mongoose with $inc failing first time then working in next attempts

Tags: node.js, mongoose

findOneAndUpdate not working and throwing erromessage 'update parameter must be an object'

Versions used :
Mongod server- 4.0.6
Mongodb driver -3.0.5
Mongoose - 5.5.1
Node -10.15.x

```
let incrementCount=1;
//dbColl is mongoose.connection.collection((String)(collectionName));
    dbColl=getDb(collectionName);
    return dbColl.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id:"URLShorteningIdentifier"
    },
    {
        $inc:{
            sequence : incrementCount
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        returnOriginal:false
    }
    )
```

And following is the stacktrace :

```
{ MongoError: update parameter must be an object
    at Function.create (\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:43:12)
    at toError (\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
    at Collection.findOneAndUpdate (\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1552:11)
    at NativeCollection.(anonymous function) [as findOneAndUpdate] (\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:28)
    at NativeCollection.Collection.doQueue (\node_modules\mongoose\lib\collection.js:126:30)
    at immediate (\node_modules\mongoose\lib\collection.js:86:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Schema:

```
{_id:"URLShorteningIdentifier", sequence :1}
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace as well, also the schema of your collection? Can not see an issue in the query?

Comment: in my local db has the structure for this counter implementation and i am not using any schema from mongoose as i already have the collection with documents created there. @HaroonKhan I updated the error log. {_id:"URLShorteningIdentifier"}

Comment: DB and collection are already created so just wanted to use the counter to get the next sequence with `findOneAndUpdate`. this should work right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem when `findOneAndUpdate` is being called *before* the connection to MongoDB has fully been set up (so before the connection has emitted an `open` event).

Internally, Mongoose queues commands until the connection has been made, and "replays" those commands when the connection is up.

However, this fails (in this case) when you're using methods that are provided by the underlying MongoDB driver, like the `findOneAndUpdate` that you use. In that case, the arguments for the command aren't being queued properly, and when they get replayed from the queue, an error is thrown.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or simply the consequence of using a driver method directly. It doesn't happen when you use Mongoose's `findOneAndUpdate` (`Model.findOneAndUpdate()`).

Alternatively, wait until the connection has been opened before issuing commands.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep ! Seems that issue was because of the mongo driver usage. After using mongoose model , issue is gone. :D